# With jQuery, how to draw square Divs inside the document, clicking a point in the viewport then moving the mouse?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drawing, html

I want to draw inside the DOM squared Divs, clicking a random point in the viewport then moving the mouse with this effect...

http://www.vegabit.com/test/example_create_div_on_mouse_move.jpg

in jQuery... and without any plugin...

Thank You in advance!

Max

Comment: why without plugin, pugin is same as code you will write..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this?
http://jsbin.com/azare

found it here 
http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-en/browse_thread/thread/9158d61a96061873?pli=1

Comment: What a nice code, but not working with the new jQuery and jQueryUI. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean draw inside ?

You can drag the div using jquery ui draggable.

[Link](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/)